# Python3. Setuptools. Добавление локального пакета в сборку

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup

Есть локально собранный пакет (например **main-0.1.tar.gz**).
Есть другой пакет (например **base-0.1**), который требует в зависимости **main-0.1**

Нужно, что бы при последующей установки пакета **base-0.1**, пакет **main-0.1** так-же был установлен.

Т.е. указать в **install_requires** можно только пакеты с **PyPI**, а вот добавить пакеты в сборку - не ясно как.

Можно добавить в архив **base-0.1** пакет **main-0.1.tag.gz** с помощью MANIFEST.in (`include main-0.1.tag.gz`). Но дальше **dependency_links**, например, не работает корректно.

Как добавить локальный пакет в сборку другого пакета и последующую его установку вместе с другим пакетом, как если бы он подтягивался с **PyPI** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел примерное решение. Не знаю на сколько это по феншую, но работает.

В **MANIFEST.in** добавляем `include main-0.1.tar.gz`

В **setup.py** в конце файла(после вызова `setup()`) дописываем:

```
if 'sdist' not in sys.argv[1]:
    os.system('pip install main-0.1.tar.gz')
```

Условие может быть другим, если, например, для сборки не используется `sdist` (`python setup.py sdist`). Главное как-то определить, что это запуск `setup` на сборку, а не на установку (`pip install base-0.1.tar.gz` в будущем).

В таком варианте мы копируем локальный зависимый пакет в архив собираемого пакета, и распространяется он, соответственно, вместе с ним. И устанавливается так-же.